# How to check if column exists in a table, and not to insert into it if it doesn't

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to make a program not crash when it attempts to insert a value into a column that doesn't exist (the reason this happens in the first place is because the column names that it inserts into are coming from values red in another table which may contain typos).

If a column doesn't exist, how do I skip the `INSERT`?

```
for row in cur2:
            if row[1] > specialLimit:
               try:
                 cur.execute("INSERT INTO {}.{} (item_id) VALUES ('{}')".format(schema, table, row[0]))
                 con.commit()
               except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
                 print('Error: '+e)
```

This still gives the error:

`LINE 1: INSERT INTO load_primary.item_properties  (exotic) VALUES (...`

Answer (score 7):

You can run  a simple query before making request:

```
select exists (
  select 1 from information_schema.columns 
  where table_name ='my_table' 
  and column_name='my_column'
);
```

This would return boolean and `psycopg2` will automatically convert it ot python's boolean.

An alternative way would be to run a single query to check all the columns at once. And insert data only to those that exist. This mght be slightly more efficient.

Comment: How does it know which schema to look for the specified table in? The db I'm working with has several tables of the same name in different schemas.

Comment: you can use`table_schema` column to narrow down the search

Comment: This is akin to checking if a file exists before creating or opening it (i.e. "wrong") because it gives rise to a possible race condition: the columns can change between the checking step and the inserting step. Don't ask for permission, just do it.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson That's not necessarily the case for a transactional system like a database. Error handling can be significantly more expensive than pre-checking, requiring the use of subtransactions, etc. You also have locking facilities available to make such pre-checks safer. For example if you `LOCK TABLE my_schema.my_table IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE` then you can safely test its structure, knowing nobody else can change it before you commit or roll back. Also, the approach you advocate produces lots of error log noise in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic approach is to not ask for permission -- execute the insert in a `try/except` block; inspect the exception to understand what exception was raised; and if it was a missing column, skip over that insert, log the error, or whatever you need to do.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but I don't seem to be catching the right error e.g. psycopg2.DatabaseError

Comment: Check what the returned exception, e.g. if you name the exception parameter `exc`, just put a `print exc, type(exc)` in the `except` block.